# Verification of topology

Tags: general-topology

*This is all new to me this semester, have mercy :)*

Let $X$ be an infinite set and the collection
$$\tau = \left\lbrace U\subset X : U=\emptyset\quad\mbox{or}\quad X\setminus U\ \mbox{is finite} \right\rbrace $$
Decide whether $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space.
It's apparent that $\emptyset ,X\in \tau$. [if we consider $\emptyset$ to be finite, which it should be]

Let $I$ be a set of indices and $U_j\in\tau, j\in I$.
$$\bigcup_{j\in I}U_j =: Y\subset X\quad\quad\quad Y\overset{?}\in\tau $$
Since $X$ is infinite, assuming $U_j\neq\emptyset$ for some $j\in I$, $Y$ must also be infinite [because $X\setminus U_j$ is finite], therefore by construction, $X\setminus Y$ is finite, therefore $Y\in\tau$. [is this  convincing?]
**Edit: Nope, not convincing!**

$$X\setminus Y = X\setminus\bigcup_{j\in I}U_j =\bigcap_{j\in J}(X\setminus U_j)$$
Since all $X\setminus U_j$ are finite, their intersection must also be finite, therefore $Y\in\tau$. That's better

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $U_j\in\tau, j\in\mathbb{N}, 1\leq j\leq n$.
$$\bigcap_{j=1}^n U_j =:Z $$
If $U_j=\emptyset$ for some $1\leq j\leq n$, then $Z\in\tau$. Assume $U_j\neq\emptyset$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$. We would have
$$Z = X\setminus\left ( X\setminus\bigcap_{j=1}^nU_j\right ) = X\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^n(X\setminus U_j) $$
Since all $X\setminus U_j$ are finite, their finite union is also finite and so $Z$ is infinite, so far so good.
$$X\setminus Z = X\setminus \left [X\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^n(X\setminus U_j)\right ] =\bigcup_{j=1}^n(X\setminus U_j)$$
so $X\setminus Z$ is finite, therefore $Z\in\tau$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $U_j\subseteq Y$ (where $X\setminus U_j$ is finite) you can draw the conclusion that $X\setminus Y\subseteq X\setminus U_j$.

This legalizes the conclusion that also $X\setminus Y$ is finite, hence is an element of $\tau$.

---

Concerning intersections it is enough to prove that $U\cap V\in\tau$ if $U,V\in\tau$ (so working with $n$ is redundant). If that's done then induction can be applied to make it work more generally for finite intersections.

If $X\setminus U$ and $X\setminus V$ are finite then so is $(X\setminus U)\cup(X\setminus V)=X\setminus(U\cap V)$.

If at least one of the sets $U,V$ has no finite complement, then it must equalize the set $\varnothing$ and in that case $U\cap V=\varnothing\in\tau$.

Comment: ah, cheers, I was going purely by definition, just in case, but you're right!